# Contact Form 7 allow in HTML tag area

Tags: php, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

How can I enable contact form 7 shortcode in HTML area( Where only allow html tag ) .

[contact-form-7 id="2358" title="Contact Form 1"]

Actually, I would like to allow 3rd slide of my web site.
http://vistabrand.com/

Comment: Which slider you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

You can output it in php like this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="617" title="capta contact form"]' ); ?>
```

Search on web little bit before posting, Search on web little bit before posting,
 [I found this on Google.](http://contactform7.com/faq/#Can_I_embed_a_contact_form_into_my_template_file)